# HTML with iFrames

Tags: html, iframe, video

I'm trying to create an responsive website that will hold several YouTube videos in the same line and will adjust proportionally when changing the window size.

In addition the videos are not placed beneath of the menu.
I truly tried everything and still it cannot work...

**HTML Part:**

```
<body>
    <div id="Main_Grid">
        <div id="Header">
            <a id="logo"></a>
            <a id="Search"></a>
            <a href="#" id="English">English</a>
            <nav>
                <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="current">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="Video-Container1" >
            <iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N-nb6k_6pwg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="Video-Container2" >
            <iframe width="320" height="240" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/N-nb6k_6pwg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**CSS Part:**

```
body { 
    font-size: 1.05em;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    font-family: Alef Hebrew;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    color: #555;
    height:Auto;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 76px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #c0c0c0;
    z-index: 100;
}

#Main_Grid {
    position: absolute;
    Width:95%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

#Video-Container1 {
    position:Relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-top:30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#Video-Container1 iframe {
    position:Absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

#Video-Container2 {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    padding-top:25px;
    height: Auto;
    Width:100%;
}
#Video-Container2 iframe {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    Right:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the videos as an expression of `vw` and `vh`, the viewport width and height. If you want to have multiple videos on a line, and each of them be at most 20% of the width page wide, and have a 4:3 ratio, you can write CSS like this:

```
.videoContainer {
  width: 20vw; 
  height: 15vw; /* 3/4 of 20 */
  max-height: 20vh; 
  max-width: 27vh; /* 4/3 of 20 */
}
```